# Validate Unicode Length With Regex 

Tags: c#, regex

How can I validate **۱۳۹۱/۰۹/۰۹** string with Regex

I want the length of each separate slash be exact as {4}/{2}/{2}

the Unicode range is **[\u06F0-\u06F9]**.

I have problem with length checking.

Comment: Isn't that written right to left?

Comment: You say you "have problem with length checking" - what have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin :  yes its right to left

Comment: @JonSkeet : i search and try [\u06F0-\u06F9]{4}? . i found that its match for exact number but if my first group be 5 they Regex still true

Comment: @Raika: Please post the *whole* pattern you're using. It should be easy for you to post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
"^[\u06F0-\u06F9]{4}/[\u06F0-\u06F9]{2}/[\u06F0-\u06F9]{2}$"
```

You're probably missing the `^` to make it start the match at the beginning of the string and the `$` to make it end the match at the end of the string. Without these changes strings that were longer, but that contained your expression would yield as a match.

With this change a match is only successful if the string contains your pattern and does not have any extra characters to the left or to the right of the target pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
"(^|[^\u06F0-\u06F9]{1})[\u06F0-\u06F9]{4}/[\u06F0-\u06F9]{2}/[\u06F0-\u06F9]{2}([^\u06F0-\u06F9]{1}|$)"
```

Match the date expression under **both** of the following conditions:

- Condition1: It should be *either* at the beginning of the string *or* after a single character that's not in the character range `[\u06F0-\u06F9]`
- Condition2: It should be *either* at the end of the string *or* before a single character that's not in the character range `[\u06F0-\u06F9]`

This will not match the expression in this string:

```
How can I validate ۱۱۳۹۱/۰۹/۰۹ string with Regex
-------------------^5Numbers, not matched
```

Or this string:

```
How can I validate ۱۱۳۹۱/۰۹/۰۹۹ string with Regex
------------------------------^Three numbers, not matched
```

but still will match the date expression in this string:

```
How can I validate۱۳۹۱/۰۹/۰۹string with Regex  
------------------^---------^ No whitespaces above ^, the expression is matched though
```

If you want to avoid this, i.e, just match the date expression alone, with whitespaces (and linebreaks) before and after it, use the following Regex:

```
(^|[ \t\n]{1})[\u06F0-\u06F9]{4}/[\u06F0-\u06F9]{2}/[\u06F0-\u06F9]{2}([ \t\n]{1}|$)
```

Hope that's helpful.